Having an issue accessing the EntraID access token via API call
I am currently trying to access the entraID access token via an http POST on Copilot Studios:
Currently my Post looks as such:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
Body:
{
"client_id": "4052b5a7-7355-40f0-a613-fc0dc88d2249",
"client_secret": "xxxxxxxx",
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"resource": "https://management.azure.com"
}
I keep receiving a 400 bad request response... any settings or updates to my JSON format that I should be doing to fix this.
I have tried multiple different variations of the JSON format that i have seen on other threads and created countless new Entra App registrations following microsoft documentation
Thanks

Try below script, if your want the access token for Microsoft Entra Id, change the scope to https://graph.microsoft.com/.default. if the access token is used for getting azure resources such as vm, storage account, etc, using the scope https://management.azure.com/.default
azureTokenGet.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$TenantId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$ClientId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$ClientSecret
)

$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    scope         = "https://management.azure.com/.default"
    client_id     = $ClientId
    client_secret = $ClientSecret
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $body -Headers $headers

return $token.access_token



I've tried this and am still receiving an error, do you know if there are any settings in Entra Admin center I would need to change to allow this. Thanks!

what's your error message show ?

Bot said:
Error Message: HTTP request failed with status code 400 BadRequest. Error Code: HttpRequestFailure Conversation Id: 4857f320-af12-434f-9632-88a13da4b232 Time (UTC): 2024-05-22T13:06:06.635Z
I am performing the call on the built in HTTP Call plugin in copilot Studios...
